# How to reload a function(event)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div having `position: fixed;` otherwise at a certain time on scroll down it's having `position: absolute;`.
My issue is that the `position: fixed;` of my div depends on the top of my footer. However the top of my footer changes but not the limit of the part where my div should be 'fixed'. Maybe the code would be more clear :

html :

```
<div id="header" style="height:500px; width:800px; border: 5px solid green; " >
    header
</div>

<div id="top" style="height:3000px; width:800px; border: 5px solid yellow; " >

    <button onclick="ReduceSize()"> Reduce size </button>

    <div id="comment" style="padding-bottom:30px; height:700px; width : 300px; margin-left:30px; border: 5px solid orange;" >  
    </div> 

</div>

<div id="bottom" style="height:3000px; width:800px; border: 5px solid green; " >
    footer
</div>
```

js :

```
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js'>
</script>

<script>
    function ReduceSize() {  
        var obj = document.getElementById('top');
        obj.style.height = "750px";
    }


    $(document).ready(function () {

    var haut = $('#comment').offset().top;
    var hautBottom = $('#bottom').offset().top - parseFloat( $('#comment').css('height').replace(/auto/, 0)  )  ; 

    $(window).scroll(function (event) {        
        var y = $(this).scrollTop(); 

        if(   (y >= (haut-20) ) && (y < hautBottom )     )  { 
            $('#comment').css({ position: 'fixed', top:20 });
        }else{
            if(y >= haut){  
                $('#comment').css({ position: 'absolute', top:hautBottom  });   
            }
            if(y < hautBottom ){  
                $('#comment').css({    position: 'absolute', top:parseFloat(   $('#top').offset().top)    });   
            };
        };
    }); 

});
</script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to prevent #comment overlaying the top part of the footer?

Answer (score 1):

It is not 100% clear for me, what you want to achieve, but I think this is it:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Untitled</title>
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script>
    function ReduceSize() {
        $(content).css('height', '600px');
        set_comment_position();
    }

    function set_comment_position(){

        var header  = $('#header');
        var comment = $('#comment');
        var footer  = $('#footer');
        var scroll  = $(window).scrollTop();
        var header_height           = header.outerHeight();
        var comment_height          = comment.outerHeight();
        var comment_distance_top    = header_height - scroll;
        var footer_offset_top       = footer.offset().top;
        var footer_distance_top     = footer_offset_top - scroll;
        var comment_distance_footer = footer_distance_top - comment_height;

        if (comment_distance_top <= 0) {
            if (comment_distance_footer > 0) {
                comment.css({
                    position: 'fixed',
                    top: '0px',
                    bottom : 'auto'
                });
            } else {
                comment.css({
                    position: 'absolute',
                    top: 'auto',
                    bottom: '0px'
                });
            }
        } else {
            comment.css({
                position: 'absolute',
                top: '0px',
                bottom : 'auto'
            });
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        set_comment_position()
    });
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        set_comment_position();
    });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header" style="height:100px; width:800px; background-color: lightgreen; " >
    header
    </div>
    <div id="content" style="height:800px; width:800px; background-color: lightgrey; position: relative;" >
        <div id="comment" style="height:400px; width : 300px; background-color: orange; position: absolute; top: 0px;" >
            comment
            <button onclick="ReduceSize()"> Reduce size </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer" style="height:800px; width:800px; background-color: lightgreen; " >
        footer
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The point is to wrap the positioning logic into one separate function and call this function on docready, scroll and resize.

Comment: Thank you very much, that is exactly what I was looking for !